# how to know the select id from an dynamic <select> option?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, select

I'm building an dynamic webshop with more than 30 'select' 'option' in my page.
     
In each 'select' i have also dynamic values.
     
Each value is displayed as an 'option'

```
<select class="form-control" id="seh" name="eh">
  <option value="10">Karton 10 x 1.00 kg</option>
  <option value="1.00">Verkoopeenheid 1.00 kg</option>
  <option value="1" selected="">Per kg</option>
</select>
```

When i click on the 'select' and chose an 'option', i want to display the selectIndex into an hidden input type text .

```
<input name="si" value="**?Here i want the index?**" type="hidden">
```

i want use this for the logged in users to remember the last used 'option' when they come back and log in again.

can someone help me out please?

**UPDATE **

```
<form class="form-item">

<select class="form-control" id="sel_1" name="seleh">
  <option value="8">Karton 8 x 1.05 kg</option>
  <option value="1.05">Verkoopeenheid 1.05 kg</option>
  <option value="1">Per kg</option>
</select>

<input name="newsid" id="newsid_1" value="" type="text" hidden>

<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary"> add</button>

</form>
```

this is the output of my form

below the jquery part ... it works but it affect all input#newsid_#number#
i want only affect the input#newsid_# that belongs to select#

when i clik or make changes in select#sel_4 i want the val of the selected item displayed in input#newsid_4.

```
<script>
$("select.form-control").click(function(){

  var selectedText = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
  var news         = $(this).find('input[id^=newsid_]').text();

  $('input[id^=newsid_]').attr("value", selectedText);  
});
</script>
```

Comment: simply putting it in another input field will not have it remembered for next visit. it will need to be stored In a session or db

Comment: What Dagon said, plus you can also store it client-side in a regular cookie (i.e. not a session cookie). Also, storing the selected index is a bad idea. What happens if you want to change the order of your options? Instead store the value and when you output the element to the page, check to see if that's the current value using PHP.

Comment: Also, a way to store it is to use a $.cookie object if you want to. Store it, then on page load, set it to selected again to remember the item. I can add that code also to my answer if you would like me to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Easy, just bind to the change event, and then get the "option:selected" selector with jQuery. Is that what you needed?

```
$("select.form-control).change(function(){

     var selectedText = $(this).find("option:selected").text();//the selected text

      $("#myHiddenField").attr("value", selectedText); //apply to hidden field  
});
```

Also, if the select list are going to be built dynamically after page load, then bind this way instead:

This will bind to al current and FUTURE select list.

```
  $(document)on("change", "select", function(){

     var selectedText = $(this).find("option:selected").text();//the selected text

      $("#myHiddenField").attr("value", selectedText); //apply to hidden field  
});
```

There is no reason to do some of the code below you posted. Change it to the following:

```
<script>
$("select.form-control").click(function(){

  var selectedText = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
  var $newsElement = $(this).find('input[id^=newsid_]');

  $newsElement.attr("value", selectedText);  
});
```

Comment: This watches for the change event to trigger, then when it does, it gets the currently selected text. Just apply that value to a hidden field.

Comment: euhm... this is working but only for one select ... i have ~30 select's /per page

Comment: will not help keep the value after leaving the page

Comment: Nothing will keep value after leaving the page. You have to store, as I mentioned n a cookie or a localStorage, or even a database. I mentioned that above. And yes, I do not always right exact copy paste code for people, so they ca use a topic, and then see the idea, and write it for them selves. That is the biggest part of development. remove the class selector, and only bind to $("select") and that will get all of them. Then inside the bind function, write the value, to a cookie. You could mayabe use the select's index of items, if you do not know an id. This is example is what you asked.

Comment: hi Casey, i'm using your code now. it works, but only on the the first one. when i make a change on the second 'select option' it put's the value of the second 'select option' into my first 'input #newid'. i have per 'select option' an hidden field where i want out the val of the selected value. do i need to use an unique id for the hidden fields ?

Comment: Yes you do. I would recommend using (if using a template, then can do this, bt not sure what the html looks like) to use the same id as the select, then append somthing like "_hidden". That way you can do this in a very generic way. Then, you could get the idea in the event handler of the select, and then append"_hidden", and that is your hidden field. Another way, is to use the context. Wrap a div around each section where the select and hidden field is. Then when in your handler, you just say $(this).parents("the div").find("input[type='hidden']"), and that is the context of the input.

Comment: One last way, as once stated, I DO NOT KNOW YOUR PAGE LAYOUT, but if the hidden fields are located by the selects, you can use jQuery's "closest", but this goes up traversing the DOM tree, not down. All depends on how your layout of html is structured. These ideas should give you a hint of what you need though.

Comment: I'm not using a specific template. Its a products page where i display content found in my DB. So when i click 'group-a' it selects everithing with 'group-a' found under my table 'products' and then i display them throug an foreach loop.  Inside the loop i make an form and close it just before closing the form. In that loop is even displayed my 'select'. Each select have got the same name and id ... The same for Each hidden input for my 'select text'.

Comment: Or should i put the script in the foreach loop?

Comment: That's is why, of course if they have same name this will happen. You can either choose the context route I described, or change the id inside the loops. If you want, just set id = id+n. Make n a counter of the loop. Easy and clean way to handle this.

Comment: Allright this part was easy. It was logical to make thema unique. But now how to pass my id to the jquery par . $("select.form-control).change(function(){.... I guess i'll neef the id here ...

Comment: Please update your jQuery code, and post on here, and I can help.

Comment: Inside the binder function above, you use this to get the select id. $(this).attr("id"); //gives you the current selt id that triggered the event.

Comment: i made some changes and i think it's working like it schould. $("select.form-control").click(function(){
    var selectedText = $(this).find("option:selected").val();
  var news = $(this).find('input[id^=newsid_]').text();
      $('input[id^=newsid_]').attr("value", selectedText);
});

Comment: finally it's not like it schould be. when i change the value of an option it put's the value it all hidden inputs witd id newsid_

Comment: post your output of the html so I can see it, and I will write the functions for you. Just hard without seeing the code, and how the DOM is layed out.

Comment: aaargf its not working for me. it does nothing anymore

Comment: post the html output also, and I can then for sure write all teh code. Then you can just go ov er what I did.